# How to stop WordPress showing a virtual Robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

well the problem is, I can see the robots.txt file here :

http://persian.cc

(please put a /robots.txt after the domain name)

But google cant !

I know that I can find robots.txt files in the root of a website, but hey there is no robots.txt file in mine and this robots.txt is a virtual one being made by WordPress.
Now how to stop wordpress doing that?!

OR
If I cannot stop wordpress showing that virtual robots.txt file, how can I stop google looking for it on my website? maybe a .htaccess code or something?

thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question, you can try here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What makes you think Google Cant find it? If its there when you type it in, it's there when Google requests it

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps or not. But I promised to maintain an article on robots.txt for WordPres / Joomla / PHPBB. It's still in working condition. Here it is:

http://mast3rpee.tk/?p=127

Basically what I'm doing is setting a default robot.txt and also modifying apache using .haccess file to force loading of a custom robots.php. Why? Well this solves most problems not just the one here. It also works on free hosting which can create all sorts of issues (some ban txt files! some overide robots.txt etc).

HERE IS THE CODE

### .htaccess

```
# BEGIN Robots
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<FilesMatch "^robots.(txt|php)$">
Header Set Last-Modified "Tue, 01 Jan 2013 12:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(robots)\.txt$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Robots
```

### robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Sitemap: http://{PUT YOUR DOMAIN}/sitemap.xml
Crawl-delay: 4
```

### robots.php

```
<?php
$start = "2013/01/01";  // Date you started your blog YYYY/MM/DD
$average = 30;      // Number of posts you make per month
$sitemap = "http://{PUT YOUR DOMAIN}/sitemap.xml";
// Is blog old enough
$old = ($average/30)*(time()-strtotime($start)) > 3600*24*360? true : false;
// Output proper headers
header ('Content-Type: text/plain');
header ('Cache-Control: private, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=36000');
header ('Expires: ' . gmstrftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time() + 36000));
header ('Last-Modified: ' . gmstrftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time() - 36000));

if ($old) { $custom = date("Y/m");
echo <<< ROBOTS
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /$custom
Sitemap: $sitemap
Crawl-delay: 4
ROBOTS;
} else { $custom = date("Y");
echo <<< ROBOTS
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /archives/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /$custom
Sitemap: $sitemap
Crawl-delay: 4
ROBOTS;
}
exit; ?>
```